# join on several conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables A and B

```
date      Fruit_id amount
date_1           1      5
date_1           2      1    
date_2           1      2 
....

date      Fruit_id  amount
date_1           1       2
date_1           3       2    
date_2           5       1 
....
```

and a id_table C
    fruit_id  fruit
           1  apple
    ....

And I try to get a table that shows the amount of both tables next to each other for each fruit for a certain day. I tried

```
SELECT a.date, f.fruit, a.amount as amount_A, b.amount as amount_B
from table_A a
JOIN table_C f USING(fruit_id)
LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.date = b.date AND a.fruit_id =  d.fruit_id
WHERE a.date ='myDate'
```

This now creates several rows per fruit instead of 1 and the values seem fairly random combinations of the amounts.
How can I get a neat table

```
date    fruit  A  B
myDate  apple  1  5
myDate  cherry 2  2
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested this with your data and it seems to work. You want to use a full outer join in order to include all fruits and dates from A and B :)

```
SELECT C.Name
     , COALESCE(A.Date, B.Date)
     , COALESCE(A.Amount, 0) 
     , COALESCE(B.Amount, 0)
  FROM C
  JOIN (A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON B.FruitID = A.FruitID AND B.Date = A.Date)
    ON COALESCE(A.FruitID, B.FruitID) = C.FruitID 
 ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select A.date, C.fruitname, A.amount, B.amount
from A,B,C
where
A.date = B.date
and A.fruitid = B.fruitid
and A.fruitid = C.fruitid
order by A.fruitid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.DATE as DATE,
       A.FRUIT_ID FRUIT,
       sum(A.AMOUNT) A,
       sum(B.AMOUNT) B
  from A,B
 where A.DATE = B.DATE
   and A.FRUIT_ID = B.FRUIT_ID
 group by A.DATE,A.FRUIT_ID
 order by A.DATE asc
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, one is a full join another is with subqueries.. for some reason I'll do the subquery option first.

```
select x.date, x.fruit_id,
(select a.amount from a where a.fruit_id=x.fruit_id and a.date=x.date) a, 
(select b.amount from b where b.fruit_id=x.fruit_id and b.date=x.date) b
from (select a.date,a.fruit_id from a union select b.date,
b.fruit_id from b) as x
```

Additionally you can use a full join, although I don't have oracle to test this version, I believe it will work.

```
select nvl(a.date,b.date) as date, nvl(a.fruit_id,b.fruit_id) as fruit_id,
a.amount as a, b.amount as b
from a full outer join b on b.date=a.date and b.fruit_id=a.fruit_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your joins are most likely not returning enough records. This one should returns all fruits with a record in either A or B, with the matching amounts

```
SELECT ab.date, f.fruit, ab.amount_A, ab.amount_B
table_C f
JOIN ( SELECT a.date, 
              COALESCE(a.fruit_id, b.fruit_id) as fruit_id, 
              COALESCE(a.amount, 0) as amount_A, 
              COALESCE(b.amount, 0) as amount_B
       from table_A a
       FULL OUTER JOIN table_B b ON a.date = b.date AND a.fruit_id =  d.fruit_id
     ) ab ON f.fruit_id = ab.fruit_id
```